# Create auto increment number for every user when ordering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is the most asked question, but I am failing to accomplish this task. I have a `Book` model with book_history field like

```
class Book(Models):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
   book_history_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)

       def _get_book_customer_id(self):
        b_id = self.customer
        num = 1
        while Book.objects.filter(customer=b_id).exists():
            num += 1
        return cus_ord_id

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if not self.book_history_number:
            self.book_history_number = self._get_book_customer_id()
```

my objective is to increment by when a user book something for example I have A and B users and A booked smth and `book_history_number` should be 1 next time it should 2 like this:
A: 1, 2,... n because A booked two times
B: 0  B did not booked but if B user did it would be 1.

with above code I cannot able to solve this problem. Any help please

Comment: you are only incrementing `num`, but you do not use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a number, it is better to make this an `IntegerField`. You can furthermore calculate the `Max`imum of the existing books for that number plus one:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Book(Models):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
   book_history_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def _get_book_customer_id(self):
       return Book.objects.filter(customer_id=self.customer_id).aggregate(
           numb=Max('book_history_number')+1
       )['numb'] or 0

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.book_history_number:
           self.book_history_number = self._get_book_customer_id()
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It might be worth wrapping views that use this in an atomic transaction, to avoid assigning the same number due to race conditions.